# How to append function with object as a parameter in javascript string?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  //some code here
  var content = '<div onclick="populatedata(\'' + obj.Records[t] + '\')" >';

  function populatedata(obj) {
    console.log(typeof obj);
  }
</script>
```

Now output of the above code is string, but I want object content in function populatedata.

Comment: So remove the quotes? Or just pass the index and let your function use the index to look up the right record in the object.

Comment: @LGSon Then if `obj.Records[t]` is an object, `content` will result into `<div onclick="[object Object]">`.

Comment: Do you want `populatedata` to `console.log` the requested object or a stringified version of it?

Comment: Set an event listener using DOM methods instead of injecting it in the HTML string.

Comment: @Seth
I want object in populatedata as I have to process it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nnnnnn Suggested I had passed index of record in function and received it in `populatedata`.

```
<script>
  //some code here
  var content = "<div onclick="populatedata("+t+")>";

  function populatedata(index) {
    console.log(obj.Records[index]); //this is just for illustration
    //further processing here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clarify what type `obj.Records[t]` is, but I guess it is an object. So you have problem because result of concatenation with a String is always a new string, with `toString()` applied to non-string types (`obj.Records[t]` in your case).

What you need to do is to stringify your object manually so that you control string presentation yourself:

```
var content = '<div onclick="populatedata(' + JSON.stringify(obj.Records[t]) + ')">';
```

Then result of such concatenation would be something like (if `obj.Records[t] = {name: 123}`):

```
<div onclick="populatedata({"name":123})">
```

which will allow `populatedata` invocation with proper parameter.

Comment: @dfsq
My Data is in this format:
{"0":"12","1":"dsferswda","2":"sdfgdsf","3":null,"4":"sdf","5":"sdfdsf","6":"uhgioutyuti@gn.cet","7":"2","8":"True","9":"2016-01-22 21:28:51","ID":"12","TITLE":"dsferswda","SHORT_DESCRIPTION":"sdfgdsf","LONG_DESCRIPTION":null,"APPLY_LINK":"sdf","CONTACT_PERSON":"sdfdsf","EMAILID":"uhgioutyuti@gn.cet","TYPE":"2","ACTIVE":"True","LOGDATE":"2016-01-22 21:28:51"}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to further process the argument of `populatedata`, you'll first want to stringify it, then change your function from logging the `typeof` to **just** the object.

```
var content = "<div onclick='populatedata(" + JSON.stringify(obj.Records[t]) + ")'>test</div>";
function populatedata(obj) {
  // do things with obj here
  console.log(obj);
}
```

However, as Oriol mentioned in a comment on your question, you probably don't want to take that approach. It's better to:

- Manage handlers through the dom API
- Pass data objects in programmatically as opposed to embedding them into the dom